# Android mediaplayer playing MP3s exported from iOS iPod app causes unexpected behavior

Tags: android, ios, encoding, mp3

I am working on a music player app which can allow users to upload mp3 to the server, and obviously request them back and stream in MediaPlayer.

Everything is fine when I keep inside the android environment, but if I try to stream mp3 uploaded by iPhone the nightmare begins. On the iOS side I just upload the mp3 from iPod app, and I stream it in android devices - producing different unexpected behaviours on different phones.
I also download the mp3 to play locally in Google Play Music app for reference.

HTC One :

Streaming from server - the stream will pause at one fixed position for every mp3 uploaded by iPod app. It is known that the MediaPlayer will 100% make another request at that point.
Play locally in Google Play - works perfectly

Galaxy Nexus :

Streaming from Server - MediaPlayer cannot play the mp3 and log error(1,-2147483648)
Play locally in Google Play - cannot play and return a toast saying failure occurs

Samsung Galaxy S4 :

Streaming from Server - works perfectly
Play locally in Google Play - works perfectly

It is suspected that the encoding of the mp3 in the iPod app causes the problem. Generally, should the mp3s from iPod app be preprocessed before they can be played in Android environment?